# Editing software to quickly match audio and video transitions

Tags: action-cam

I would like to create a short movie from a collection of clips, shot with an action cam, where the video transitions are synced with the beats in my audio. I have done some research and the options I have found are:

1. Quik - not suitable as I don't have a GoPro
   2 . Final cut Pro - I don't own an Mac
2. Premiere Pro - An annual subscription of £200+ is not worth it just to make a few short videos

The key feature is the synchronization of clips to the audio track. I know there are plenty of video editors out there. But I need something fast that will be able to achieve this.

Are these the only options? Are there any other fast editing programs that can generate synced video -audio transitions without spending a fortune? I would be interested in any other solutions

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times before. You'll see if you search for `free video editor` on this site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Free video editing software](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14820/free-video-editing-software)

Comment: @stib I'm not looking for any free video editor. I'm looking for something that can sync the clips to the as soundtrack quickly and without spending a lot of money.

Comment: If you want this for any arbitrary sound track you lay, then I don't know. But if you are ok with several pre-defined music tracks, then Adobe Premiere Clip can do that, it works on smartphones and tablets.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick Google search, I can see that Movavi has something like this and (as far as I can tell) is free. However, it only marks the beats for you; you'd still need to actually roll up your sleeves and cut the clips down yourself.

Adobe Premiere Elements also has a beat detector thing (I believe) but, again, I suspect that it'll just help by marking the beats on your timeline, leaving you to do the cutting.

I can't actually find something that does it all for you but, to be honest, you'll probably get better results cutting the thing yourself and it really won't take that long (I reckon about an hour or so for a 2-3 min track, if that - especially if you've already selected your clips).

Comment: It is just that the goPro software seems to detect scene changes and therefore auto splits the file and then matches the sections to the beats. I have a copy of Filmora, I noticed that they have an option for scene detection. I will do as you suggest and try and mark the beats and match them with the clip, I'm just worried that the work will be tedious and fiddly, for example a clip can be made shorter but not longer. It would be great to have a matching algorithm that optimises the clip cutting to ensure that the breaks are met.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean! Sorry - I literally thought that you were referring to just cutting down longer clips so that the cuts are on the beats, as opposed to identifying scene changes and, as you said, matching up the appropriate clips. Honestly, it might get a little tedious, but that's video editing :) I still think that you get the best results doing things yourself than relying on an algorithm (though having that do some of the hard work first would be amazing!) - I hope it's not too arduous, though and best of luck with it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Sony Vegas! You can align your audio in the timeline and split what you want. Use a clap when filming to align it for editing.

Answer (score 0):

Redgiant has a plugin that automatically does that for you. It is not free but will save you a lot of valuable time. Here's the link to it:

https://www.redgiant.com/products/shooter-pluraleyes/

Answer (score 0):

In Android devices I'm using Quik, it can import any video and photos (everything, GoPro and non GoPro footage). But the desktop version can only read GoPro footage.

I'm using Filmora for now, it has the features that closest to Quik.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using MAGIX Fastcut for this. It doesn't have many advanced features, but it does have scene selection, beat detection and automatic scene mixing according to the beat.

To put it in plain words, you select a song, click a button to do beat detection and then select the video clips you want to be fitted to the song. The program then does the cutting automatically, based on the detected beats.

Comment: *"The key feature is the synchronization of clips to the audio track."* You don't mention if it satisfied OP requirement.

Comment: I've edited my reply with a better explanation. There's a trial version if you want to try it.

Answer (score 0):

As of April 2021, several professional video editor software packages have audio beat detection. Filmora themselves wrote a blog post about the feature, and included [the competition](https://filmora.wondershare.com/video-editor/best-beat-sync-video-editing-apps.html): Premiere Elements, Cyberlink PowerDirector, Adobe Premiere Pro etc.

The following editors don't have audio beat detection:

- DaVinci Resolve [does not](https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=121933), and the community argues [you shouldn't do that much anyway, and there are workarounds](https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=69346)
- Shotcut [does not have markers even](https://forum.shotcut.org/t/markers-or-an-easy-way-of-syncing-music-to-cuts/10921), but you can [use Audacity to create click tracks, and someone wrote a Windows tool to generate a markers track](https://forum.shotcut.org/t/howto-sync-video-clips-to-beat-in-music-files/19126)
- [Kdenlive does not](https://www.reddit.com/r/kdenlive/comments/gsvxyn/ruler_bpm_in_kdenlive/)